# DateTime logic in LINQ for SQL Server CE

Tags: linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

My object 'Job' has `LastTimeFinishedRunning` which is `DateTime` and `RunIntervalMinutes` which is an `int`. I need to add them together and compare against current time.

Something like this:

```
Job jobToRun = ctx.Jobs.Where
(job => DateTime.Now > Job.LastTimeFinishedRunning.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(job.RunIntervalMinutes))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Well, the `.Add()` doesn't work of course....

neither works this:

```
DateTime.Now > EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(job.LastTimeFinishedRunning, job.RunIntervalMinutes)
```

or this:

```
DateTime.Now > System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateAdd("minute", job.RunIntervalMinutes, job.LastTimeFinishedRunning)
```

...because it's SQL Server CE provider

Any suggestions? Thx.

**Update:**

I guess my only option here is to store ticks in `LastTimeFinishedRunning` by switching it from `DateTime` to `long` in DB. So the code would look something like this:

```
long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Job jobToRun = ctx.Jobs.Where
(job => ticks > Job.LastTimeFinishedRunning + job.RunIntervalMinutes * 1000 * 10000).FirstOrDefault();
```